# Downgrade chromedriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Apparently, on the [chromedriver downloads](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) page there's only one version of chromedriver to download (by the time of the writing it's 2.43), but unfortunately my Google Chrome's version is 68 and my attempts to update it has failed so as it says that the version 68 is the newest.

So is there any way to either downgrade chromedriver or forcibly update Google Chrome? I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view all versions of the chrome driver from  [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)

So if you want chromedriver 2.42 just open the folder named 2.42

Comment: Thanks, didn't think I could just go up the tree for some reason